# try to find algo on my array

Tags: algorithm, tabs

I am begginners in python and i want did a program that find the shift in an array : 
input : [16, 40, 42, 46, 47, 41, 43, 48, 49, 52]
and i want find the shift of 1, 2 and 3 between the several numbers.
output :

```
{0: [46 - 47], 1: [48 - 49]}
{0: [40 - 42], 1: [41 - 43]}
{0: [49 - 52]}
```

I have try this :

```
tab = [16, 40, 42, 46, 47, 41, 43, 48]
for i, j in enumerate(tab):
    try:
        if tab[i + 1] - tab[i] == 1:
            stock = i
        if tab[i + 1] - tab[i] == 2:
            stock2 = i
    except:
        print ("")

print (tab)
print ('Shift of one : ' +  '[%d' % tab[stock] + ' - %d]' % tab[stock + 1])
print ('Shift of two : ' + '[%d' % tab[stock2] + ' - %d]' % tab[stock2 + 1])
```

Tank's you very much !!!

Answer (score 1):

I hope I have understood your problem correctly.

```
tab = [16, 40, 42, 46, 47, 41, 43, 48, 49, 52]
shiftList = [list() , list() , list()]
for i in range(0, len(tab)-1):
    for gap in range (0,len(shiftList)):
        if tab[i + 1] - tab[i] == gap + 1 :
            shiftList[gap].append((tab[i],tab[i + 1])); 
print (shiftList)
```

We use a list of list of tuple. The list index gives the gap and the list of list stores the pairs of shifts as tuples

Output is:

```
[
 [(46, 47), (48, 49)],
 [(40, 42), (41, 43)],
 [(49, 52)]
]
```

Comment: thank's you very much, i have just still a small problem, i want my tab change as every cycle : tab = [2, 4, 9, 0, 87, 23, 24] in second tour for example